# How to force link translation in laravel 4 mcamara

Tags: laravel-4, translation, laravel-routing, laravel-localization, routelocalization-mvc

How to get translated(to chosen language) url from named route? (or how to switch language and make Redirect::route(...) to localized link)

I use:
php Laravel 4 (L4)  mcamara/laravel-localization (LaravelLocalization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple :) just use

```
$lang = App:getLocale(); // two letters lang eg. 'en', 'pl'...
return Redirect::to( LaravelLocalization::getURLFromRouteNameTranslated($lang,
'routes.site.dashboard') );
```

Caution! We assume that routes english translations for key 'site.dashboard' are in file `app/lang/en/routes.php`

If you have route with parameters for instance: `'companies.edit'   => 'companies/{company}/edit'` in routes.php file 
then you can use:

```
$lang = App:getLocale(); // two letters lang eg. 'en', 'pl'...
Redirect::to(LaravelLocalization::getURLFromRouteNameTranslated($lang,
'routes.companies.edit', ['company' => $company->id]) );
```

That's all :)